Content Security Policy causing double GETs and POSTs in Safari / Firefox?
I have an ASP.NET MVC site that started giving a new problem today.  I have forms being POSTed twice, and when checking logs, I see GETs are being made twice as well.
This is happending in Firefox today, and maybe in Safari for a week or so.
It seems to be because of my CSP.  When I remove the CSP header, this behaviour stops.
Here is my CSP defined in web.config FYI
<add name="Content-Security-Policy" value="  default-src 'self';
  img-src 'self' *.stripe.com *.bing.com;
  connect-src 'self' *.google-analytics.com checkout.stripe.com;
  frame-src 'self' checkout.stripe.com;
  script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' *.google-analytics.com *.googletagmanager.com checkout.stripe.com *.bing.com;
  style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' *.googleapis.com;
  font-src 'self' *.gstatic.com"  />

Is it just my site, or is anyone else seeing this?

It's not the server if a client is sending two POSTs. Are you possibly seeing a "preflight" OPTIONS (still XMLHttpsRequest, but not POST)?

No, it must be the browser reacting to the CSP being sent by the server.  This is POST and GET , not Ajax.
